# Powershell module DBATools command giving error

Tags: powershell, dbatools

I am getting following error now:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Test-DBADbCompatibility -SqlInstance localhost -Database EfficaDB

Cannot convert value "Version150" to type 
"Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.CompatibilityLevel". Error: "Unable to match the 
 identifier name Version150 to a valid enumerator name. 
Specify one of the following enumerator names and try again:Version60, Version65, 
Version70, Version80, Version90, Version100, Version110, Version120, Version130, Version140"
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\dbatools\1.1.40\allcommands.ps1:77485 char:93
+ ... r.Management.Smo.CompatibilityLevel]"Version$($server.VersionMajor)0"+
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : SubstringDisambiguationEnumParseThrewAnException
```

I have installed latest version of DBATools into the server.

Comment: It looks like you are using SQL 2019 and DBATools is only compatible with up to 2017 according to their site on the support section. https://dbatools.io/getting-started/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following statements at the start of the PowerShell script file, which solved the error:

```
import-module DBATools
import-module sqlserver
```